# C# Get the SelectedDate.Day String value and bind it to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, calendar

[image]

I have this calendar date run on aspx application

```
            <div>
                <asp:Calendar runat="server" ID="calendar" SelectionMode="Day" OnSelectionChanged="DateChanged" ondayrender="DateRange"></asp:Calendar>
            </div>

            <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 30px; display: inline-block;">
                <asp:GridView ID="calendarsubjects" CssClass="myGridStyle" runat="server">
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
```

and its code behind:

```
 protected void DateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        calendarsubjects.DataSource = calendar.SelectedDate.Day.ToString();
        calendarsubjects.DataBind();    
    }
```

in my code:
The calendar only gets the number of the selected day. Is it possible to get only the string value of the day. Like when I click a specific number `8` it will display the `Wed` string of the Selected Day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SelectedDate is a DateTime. Start from there.

A DateTime has a DayOfWeok property that may be useful. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx You could also just do a ToString method with a formatting string for the day of week, as you'd want it presented

```
SelectedDate.ToString("ddd")
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Here's a link to a formatting guide.

Comment: Thanks sir, this greatly helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get just the day (String) portion of a date.
Just use the appropriate string format expression.

```
calendar.SelectedDate.Day.ToString("ddd");
```

Please have a look at the following page for futher format expressions:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I am sure this would give you an error when you try to

```
calendarsubjects.DataSource = calendar.SelectedDate.Day.ToString();
calendarsubjects.DataBind();
```

because your `calendarsubjects` is a `GridView` and GridView is there to take the values in List, IEnumerable or Array.

So better you should just remove the code of Grid and Assign the values directly to the div something like this

```
<div>
    <asp:Calendar runat="server"
                  ID="calendar"
                  SelectionMode="Day"
                  OnSelectionChanged="DateChanged"
                  ondayrender="DateRange"></asp:Calendar>
</div>
<div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 30px; display: inline-block;" ID="calendarsubjects"></div>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void DateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    calendarsubjects.InnerHtml = calendar.SelectedDate.ToString("ddd");
}
```

Hope this will do what you might be looking for.